# How to access the Grafana time interval range for DrillDown links to an ElasticSearch page

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to add a drilldown link to an Elastic search link in a Grafana chart. I'm able to use the variables that are already defined in my panel, but I also want to make use of the current time interval when creating the URL for elastic search.

I have tried using the following variables in the URL based on different online posts, hoping that they would be replaced by Grafana when the URL is clicked.

- $__interval
- $timeInterval
- $interval

but, nonw have been converted to the time range value that is currently selected.

e.g.:
Url in Grafana:

> https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(from:now-***$__interval***,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:'logs-*',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20**environment:$environment**'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))

Expected Url when user clicks the chart:

> https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(from:now-***1h***,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:'logs-*',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20**environment:Development**'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))

Actual Url when user clicks the chart:

> https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(from:now-***$__interval***,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:'logs-*',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20**environment:Development**'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))

The $environment variable is being replaced as expected but the $__interval variable is not being replaced which causes the URL to not be parsed correctly by Elastic Search when trying to display the page.

[image: Drilldown link for SingleStat Chart]

Answer (score 1):

Possible starting from Grafana 6.0, use this snippet:

Url: "/dashboard-id/dashboard-name?var-variable1=${__cell}&from=$__from&to=$__to

Comment: I think OP wants to link to Elasticsearch, not back to a Grafana dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the **absolute** `from` and `to`, rather than the relative now-based time range, as follows (using your example URL):

> [https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(**from:'${__from:date:iso}',mode:quick,to:'${__to:date:iso}'**))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:'logs-*',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20environment:$environment'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))](https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(**from:%27$%7B__from:date:iso%7D%27,mode:quick,to:%27$%7B__to:date:iso%7D%27**))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:%27logs-*%27,interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:%27severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20environment:$environment%27),sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc)))

This results in a URL like this:

> [https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(**from:'2023-07-12T14:38:09.298Z',mode:quick,to:'2023-07-12T17:38:09.298Z'**))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:'logs-*',interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:'severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20environment:Development'),sort:!('@timestamp',desc))](https://elastic.local.dev/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:10000),time:(**from:%272023-07-12T14:38:09.298Z%27,mode:quick,to:%272023-07-12T17:38:09.298Z%27**))&_a=(columns:!(_source),index:%27logs-*%27,interval:auto,query:(language:lucene,query:%27severity:FATAL%20AND%20%20environment:Development%27),sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc)))

Note two important points:

1. We wrap the variables in quotes, since we're formatting them as time strings rather than numeric epoch-seconds or epoch-millis
2. We use the `:iso` modifier to force the format.

Can Elasticsearch accept epoch-seconds or millis in its link?  Maybe.  I'm not sure... but that would be another way to go.

See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-data-links/#time-range-panel-variables for more info